# Unsupported Oracle data type USERDEFINED encountered

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle

```
SqlDataSource chargesDS = (SqlDataSource)lv2Item.FindControl("charges_gv_datasource");
string sql = "WITH relevant_ids AS (SELECT ir.result_id AS relevant_result_id FROM inspection_result_tbl ir WHERE ir.inspection_job_id= '" + incidentID.Text + "') SELECT ir.charge_id, COLLECT(ir.result_id) AS result_ids, ch.charge_progress, ch.claim_verification, ch.hours_allowed, ch.sap_notification, ch.total_checked, ch.charge FROM inspection_result_tbl ir LEFT JOIN relevant_ids ON ir.result_id=relevant_ids.relevant_result_id LEFT JOIN charges_tbl ch ON ir.charge_id=ch.charge_id WHERE ir.charge_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY ir.charge_id, ch.charge_progress, ch.claim_verification, ch.hours_allowed, ch.sap_notification, ch.total_checked, ch.charge";
                    chargesDS.SelectCommand = sql;
```

I have a data source as im giving it the select command shown above but it is giving me the error:

Unsupported Oracle data type USERDEFINED encountered.

With Stack trace:

```
[NotSupportedException: Unsupported Oracle data type USERDEFINED encountered.]
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleColumn.Describe(Int32& offset, OracleConnection connection, OciErrorHandle errorHandle) +384881
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader.FillColumnInfo() +311
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader..ctor(OracleCommand command, OciStatementHandle statementHandle, String statementText, CommandBehavior commandBehavior) +163
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +268
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +9
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +19
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +221
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +573
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +161
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +2790902
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +27
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +261
   BMW.XSAPPS.RR.PartsQuality.SandboxPart.SandboxPartUserControl.setChargesGV() +891
   BMW.XSAPPS.RR.PartsQuality.SandboxPart.SandboxPartUserControl.populatePage(Boolean filterActive) +5827
   BMW.XSAPPS.RR.PartsQuality.SandboxPart.SandboxPartUserControl.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1310
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +350
   BMW.XSAPPS.RR.PartsQuality.SandboxPart.SandboxPart.CreateChildControls() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error? I think it's something to do with the COLLECT part.

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably correct.  COLLECT requires a custom type and a CAST to a standard datatype.

Comment: Ahh ok. How do I go about casting it? I tried but not getting any luck.

Comment: Here's some info: <http://oracle101.blogspot.com/2008/08/oracle-collect-function.html>

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this just by replacing

`using System.Data.OracleClient;`

with

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

You have to add Reference also for above change: `Oracle.DataAccess`